# How to call a number from another function into a function?

Tags: javascript

How can I call the "x" from function numOne into function numTwo? Is there any simpler way to do this? Or how can I call the result from numOne into numTwo?

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Function Testing</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function numOne(x, y){
                var x = 3;
                var y = 4;
                var result = x+y;
                numTwo();
            }
            function numTwo(){
                alert(x);
            }
        </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You can make it global, or pass it to `numTwo` manually: `numTwo(x);`

Comment: How can i make it global?

Comment: Make it global by pulling var x = 3 out of the function

Comment: Change each occurrence of `numTwo()` to `numTwo(x)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the result to `numTwo`:

```js
function numOne(x, y){
    var result = x+y;
    numTwo(result);
}

function numTwo(r){
    alert(r);
}

numOne(2, 3);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do with global value

```
var x;
function numOne(x, y){
    x=3;
    var y = 4;
    var result = x+y;
    numTwo();
}
function numTwo(){
    alert(x);
}
```

or with adding a parameter to numTwo function

```
function numOne(x, y){
    var x = 3;
    var y = 4;
    var result = x+y;
    numTwo(x);
}
function numTwo(t){
    alert(t);
}
```